# Add new environment variable to every container by Kustomize

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

Is there any possibility to add (by patch) new environment variable to **every** container by Kustomize? Currently I can manage to pass it to some containers defined by `name` but I want not to set the `name`.

Comment: looks like the same problem like here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72301379/kustomize-patch-every-item-in-a-list

Comment: @criztovyl thank you! yes, it seems that there is a similar problem